# Generar HTML a partir de XML

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xsl

Tengo una duda con la ultima parte del XSL que estoy haciendo. Tengo que generar el html de la parte de "Tiendas y numero de clientes". No consigo ordenar las tiendas tal y como se quiere en la imagen.

[image: Tabla de Sucursales]

Dejo el XML y el archivo XSL que llevo generados hasta ahora

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="LMSGI05_1819.xsl"?>
<ProduccionesCosta>
    <ventas>
      <sucursal id="PRO01-14">
        <nombre>Cosas del cine, S.L</nombre>
              <direccion>
                  <calle>Calle Américas</calle>
                  <numero>2</numero>
                  <cp>04500</cp>
                  <localidad>Mojacar</localidad>
                  <provincia>ALMERÍA</provincia>
              </direccion>
        <apertura>2013</apertura>
        <ventas anio0="10500" anio1="12400" anio2="13600" anio3="15500" anio4="10200" anio5="12000" comision="15"/>    
        </sucursal>
         <sucursal id="PRO03-16">
            <nombre>Luis López Producciones, S.L.</nombre>
            <direccion>
                <calle>Calle Rota</calle>
                <numero>s/n</numero>
                <cp>04740</cp>
                <localidad>Roquetas de Mar</localidad>
                <provincia>ALMERÍA</provincia>
            </direccion>
            <apertura>2016</apertura>
            <ventas anio0="0" anio1="0" anio2="0" anio3="0" anio4="20200" anio5="21000" comision="18"/>    
        </sucursal>
         <sucursal id="PRO03-15">
            <nombre>Atrezzo, C.B.</nombre>
            <direccion>
                <calle>Calle Central</calle>
                <numero>44</numero>
                <cp>04170</cp>
                <localidad>El Parador</localidad>
                <provincia>ALMERÍA</provincia>
            </direccion>
            <apertura>2015</apertura>
           <ventas anio0="0" anio1="0" anio2="13600" anio3="15500" anio4="10200" anio5="12000" comision="21"/>    
        </sucursal>
         <sucursal id="DIS04-17">
            <nombre>Ven a verlo, S.A.</nombre>
            <direccion>
                <calle>Calle Mayor</calle>
                <numero>103</numero>
                <cp>41900</cp>
                <localidad>Camas</localidad>
                <provincia>SEVILLA</provincia>
            </direccion>
            <apertura>2017</apertura>
            <ventas anio0="0" anio1="0" anio2="0" anio3="0" anio4="18200" anio5="22000" comision="9"/>    
        </sucursal>
    </ventas>
    <areas>
        <area>
            <nombre num_clientes="786">Prodcucciones Costa</nombre>
            <autonomia codigo="AN">Andalucía</autonomia>
            <puntosventa>
              <tienda num_clientes="198">Roquetas de Mar</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="123">Almería centro</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="156">Adra</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="141">Aguadulce</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="168">La Mojonera</tienda>
            </puntosventa>
            <identificador>AL</identificador>
        </area>  
        <area>
            <nombre num_clientes="143">Distribuciones Costa Centro</nombre>
            <autonomia codigo="AN">Andalucía</autonomia>
            <puntosventa>
              <tienda num_clientes="18">Sevilla centro</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="50">Sevilla este</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="36">Córdoba</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="11">Huelva</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="28">Almonte</tienda>
            </puntosventa>
            <identificador>SE</identificador>
        </area>
        <area>
            <nombre num_clientes="624">Distribuciones Costa Valencia</nombre>
            <autonomia codigo="CV">Comunidad Valenciana</autonomia>
            <puntosventa>
              <tienda num_clientes="154">Valencia ciudad</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="350">Chiva</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="120">Puig</tienda>
            </puntosventa>
            <identificador>VA</identificador>
        </area> 
        <area>
            <nombre num_clientes="201">Producciones Costa Cáceres</nombre>
            <autonomia codigo="EX">Extremadura</autonomia>
            <puntosventa>
              <tienda num_clientes="58">Cáceres</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="62">Tejeda de Tiétar</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="66">Serradilla</tienda>
              <tienda num_clientes="15">Plasencia</tienda>
            </puntosventa>
            <identificador>EX</identificador>
        </area>
    </areas>
</ProduccionesCosta>
```

### Producciones Costa

ID Sucursal
                    Nombre Sucursal
                    Dirección Sucursal
                    Año de Apertura
                    2013
                    2014
                    2015
                    2016
                    2017
                    2018
                    Media Ventas
                    Total Comisión
                    Tipo

```
            <xsl:for-each select = "ProduccionesCosta/ventas/sucursal">

                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "@id"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "nombre"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "direccion"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "apertura"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "ventas/@anio0"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "ventas/@anio1"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "ventas/@anio2"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "ventas/@anio3"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "ventas/@anio4"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "ventas/@anio5"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "sum(ventas/@anio0) + sum(ventas/@anio1) + sum(ventas/@anio2) + sum(ventas/@anio3) + sum(ventas/@anio4)+ sum(ventas/@anio5)"/> </td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "ventas/@comision"/></td>
                </tr>

            </xsl:for-each>



        </table>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>

        <table>
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th><h2>Areas de Actuación Producciones Costa</h2>
                <h5>Por zonas regionales, orden numero de clientes de menor a mayor, lista ordenada</h5>
                </th>    
            </tr>
        </table>

        <xsl:for-each select = "ProduccionesCosta/areas/area">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "nombre"/> (<xsl:value-of select = "autonomia"/> [<xsl:value-of select = "autonomia/@codigo"/>] - <xsl:value-of select = "nombre/@num_clientes"/>)
                </li>
            </ol>
         </xsl:for-each>

        <br></br>
        <br></br>

        <table>
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th><h2>Tiendas y número de clientes</h2>
                <h5>Por id de zona regional en orden alfabetico inverso y tiendas por numero de clientes de mayor a menor, lista no ordenada</h5>
                </th>    
            </tr>
        </table>


        <ul>
            <li>
                **Esta es la parte que no consigo hacer.**
            </li>   
       </ul>
```

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mas que verificar donde esta tu error te dejo un ejemplo funcional que hice hace tiempo para elaboarar algo similar con xml, sslt y c#:

en la carpeta de debug agregas el siguiente archivo
contactDetail.xml

dentro de este archivo agrega el contenido:

```
<contactos>
<Contact_Details>  
<Contact_ID>001</Contact_ID>  
<Contact_Number>088888888</Contact_Number>  
<Contact_Name>Mohan</Contact_Name>  
<Contact_Location>Chennai</Contact_Location>  
</Contact_Details>  
<Contact_Details>  
<Contact_ID>002</Contact_ID>  
<Contact_Number>099999999</Contact_Number>  
<Contact_Name>Abilash</Contact_Name>  
<Contact_Location>Bangalore</Contact_Location>  
</Contact_Details>
</contactos>
```

despues el esquema de transformacion creas el archivo schemaContact.xslt
(lo importante es el for-each y como se leen las prop contenindas.) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="contactos">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ContactID</td>
        <td>ContactNumber</td>
        <td>ContName</td>
        <td>ContactLocation</td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Contact_Details">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Contact_ID"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Contact_Number" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Contact_Name"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Contact_Location"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

finalmente si haces una prueba rapida en un proyecto de consola escribes:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xsltPath = "schemaContact.xslt";
            string xmlPath = "contactDetail.xml";

            string hmtlTable = TransformXMLTOHTML(xmlPath,xsltPath);
        }

        static string TransformXMLTOHTML(string xmlFileName, String XSLTFilename)
        {
            XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XMLDoc.Load(xmlFileName);

            StringWriter HTMLString = new StringWriter();
            XslCompiledTransform xmltransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xmltransform.Load(XSLTFilename);   
            xmltransform.Transform(XMLDoc, null, HTMLString);  
            return HTMLString.ToString();
        }
    }
```

y listo esto te genera una tabla con dos registros.